# Is "Bunch of people" a valid phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage, register

Some time ago I was told that use of the expression *bunch of people* is incorrect. Apparently, *bunch* should not be used along with *people* meaning *group of people*.

But the problem is that I can hear that expression from lots of people, especially non-native English speakers.

Can you please explain whether *bunch of people* is correct or not and why?

Comment: If someone says _bunch of peoples_ is it wrong? I'm thinking we should not use peoples like that.

Comment: @birsh - Normally, yes, avoid that phrasing. I suppose there could be a few special circumstances, however, like: _My favorite day of the Olympics is the opening ceremonies. You can see Kenyans, Chinese, Estonians, Argentinians, Haitians – a bunch of peoples all marching together._

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm a native speaker of English, and *bunch of people* does not sound wrong to me, nor do I suspect, to most native speakers (academics excluded; see below). The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) reports it used about a fifth as often as "group of people", which is certainly somewhat promising as far as it being "correct".

But I can't really say whether or not it is correct without knowing *why* the person who told you it's incorrect said that. It might be that it's considered rude to think of people as a *bunch*—I disagree, but if that's the case, whether it's right or wrong is going to depend on your specific audience.

Just in case, though, I checked the OED since it is far more knowledgeable than me, and interestingly enough, this seems to be of relevance:

> 3. A collection or cluster of things of the same kind, either growing together (as a bunch of grapes), or fastened closely together in any way (as a bunch of flowers, a bunch of keys); also a portion of a dress gathered together in irregular folds.
>
> 4. fig. A collection, ‘lot’. Also, a company or group of persons.

Definition 3 is the one that we're usually dealing with, and it seems to fairly clearly imply that *bunch of people* doesn't work, since people don't grow together (twins, triplets, etc. excepted) and usually aren't fastened together.

Definition 4 seems like it would work, but every usage it cites has *bunch* in isolation; it was never used in the form *bunch of people*.

I didn't see any other relevant definitions, so *bunch of people* may not be formally correct after all; either way, *group of people* is much more common and appears to be uncontroversial in usage.

Comment: Person who advised not to use that expression was my English teacher (non-native English speaker). I guess, by saying "incorrect", she meant "informal" or something similar. So I never had a chance to clarify that until now. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: So according to Oxford: 'bunch of people' is tautological.  It essentially means a group of people of people.

Comment: @mcalex: No, "a bunch *of* sticks" is just a pile of sticks. "My bunch" will be a group of my friends, "the rowdy bunch" will be a group of noisy, obnoxious people. Interestingly, "A bunch *of* people" is not really a group as such! It's many unrelated or loosely related people in one place, a small crowd.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the phrase *bunch of people* is not wrong; in fact it's very right. The phrase is very popular in its informal use. However, phrases such as  *a group of people* or  *a crowd of people* are preferred in formal meetings.

Comment: +1. I might invite a bunch of people out for lunch or have meetings with a bunch of people. But I would never write "bunch of people" on a document.

Answer (score 1):

There is one time when you can use the term “bunch” when referring to a collection of people. That would be if you say something on the lines of :

> My brother and his *bunch* are crazy about football.

Any other circumstance will have you using terms like *array*, *collection*, *group*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

*A bunch of people* is informal phrase for *many people* - not organized as a group.

Examples of use:

- *You come to work late by two hours, and a co-worker informs you "A bunch of people called asking about you. It seems there's some kind of emergency."* - They were not an organized group, he simply received a number of questions over the phone and in person.
- *You organize a party. "If the room is not big enough, a bunch of people will fit in the garden"* - it's less than "a lot" and definitely less official than "many" which would sound somewhat stiff in this context.
- At a shop: *We had a bunch of customers in the morning but later the tide subsided a little.* - there were lots of customers.

Note this will not hold with other contexts of *bunch* in relation to people. "My bunch" will be my group of friends. "They are a funny bunch" - they may or may not be a group, but they are fun. Also, these bunches will be usually smaller than the "bunch of people" mentioned earlier - five friends will be a bunch, but five customers waiting for the shop to open, not really.

Answer (score 0):

Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English has bunch as group of people, informal in no. 2:   a friendly bunch of people.
I think it can be used in a negative sense in certain contexts.